# Ideals of a polynomial ring $R[x]$ - example

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, ideals, real-numbers

Can you provide me some examples of an ideal $I$ of a polynomial ring $R[x]$.

I need the example for which the set defined below:

$X=\{x \in R: f(x)=0,  \forall f \in I \}$

is empty. I know, that e.g. $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ could belong to such an ideal.

Comment: I think you are a bit confused: your set is a subset of $R$, how can a polynomial belong to it? Anyway, if you pick $I=xR[x]$, then $\forall f \in I$ you have $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Mentioned polynomial belongs to $I$ (which is a subset of $R[x]$), not the $R$ itself.

Comment: Sorry for my English! I corrected the question.

Comment: You can trivially take $I=R[x]$. Since $1\in I$ (or any nonzero constant polynomial), there are no common zeros of $I$. The weak nullstellensatz actually shows that this is the best you can do when $R$ is an algebraically closed field, as the set of common zeros of any proper ideal is nonempty.

Comment: When I take $I=R[x]$ then the set $X$ defined in the question is not empty. I need it to be empty. I corrected the initial question sorry for that.

Comment: @supertramp when you take $I=R[x]$, the set $X$ is empty for the reason that user Ben West explained in the first line of his previous comment.

Comment: oh rlly u r right!

Comment: any non trivial exapmle?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found non-trivial example:

$I = $ { $f \in R[x] :f |  (x^2 + 1) $  }

Then, $X$ defined in my question is empty, since $(x^2 + 1) \in I$, and $(x^2 + 1)$ has no roots in $R$. Thank you very much for discussion in comments.